# Import module in XQuery (PHP + Zorba)

Tags: php, xpath, xquery, zorba

I'm writing an application in php to query huge xml files (GB) with Zorba XQuery processor (v2.6.0) and to do so I'm trying to use the XML Streaming described here:

http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2012/05/31/XML_Streaming

Here's the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'XQueryProcessor.php';

$xquery = new XQueryProcessor();

$query = '

    import module namespace file = "http://expath.org/ns/file";     
    import module namespace p = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/xml";
    import schema namespace opt = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/xml-options";:)

    let $raw-data as xs:string := file:read-text("C:\TEMP\traces\2011_03\Orders201103.xml")
    let $pages := p:parse($raw-data, <opt:options>
                                         <opt:parse-external-parsed-entity opt:skip-root-nodes="1"/>
                                     </opt:options>)

    for $page in $pages
    return
        $page
   ';

$xquery->importQuery($query);

$result = $xquery->execute();

echo $result;
?>
```

The code above doesn't work. No error codes, no stack traces, simply doesn't return anything to the web browser.

I think the problem is that it doesn't import the namespaces as when I execute a simple query without imports, it does it successfully and when I add an import sentence, it fails. When it fails the web browser shows me that if the URI did not found the resource as told here:

*If, after searching all URI path directories, no match is found for a given URI, Zorba will by default fall back to interpretting the URI as a URL and loading the resource via HTTP (assuming the URI has the http: scheme)*

http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/documentation/2.7.0/zorba/uriresolvers

I've also looked into the zorba installation folder and the way the import URI is transformed (in the link above) and it seems that it's all ok.

For example the file module is in the following path (beware it's a core module):

C:\Program Files\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.6.0\share\zorba\uris\core\2.6.0\org\expath\ns\file.xq

I'm developing on Windows and using a standard WAMP installation for Apache and PHP.

Does somebody know what's wrong with my code or environment?

edit: I've just noticed that the query runs ok from the command line so maybe it's not the URI transformation